# adding feeback page to scanning function:ionic 2 app

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have developed an app to launch a url and added the scan fucntion to it. I would like to add a feedback page(I mean , once i scan the qr code, i would like to see the result in next page). The scan fucntion works fine and I have generated a page as well but once i add this the whole function doesn't work.
Can anyone give some suggestions,it would be really helpful, been stuck on this for weeks now.thank you.

```
 **Home.ts**

import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {Platform} from 'ionic-angular';
import {BarcodeScanner} from 'ionic-native';
import {ScannedPage} from '../scanned-page/scanned-page';
@Component({
templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
 private barcodeText: String;
 private barcodeFormat: String;
 private platform: Platform;
 private navController: NavController;

 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, platform: Platform) {
    this.platform = platform;
    this.navController = navCtrl;
}
scanningDone(data) {
    this.navController.push(ScannedPage, {
    data: data
    });
}  

doScan() {    
    console.log('scannig product barcode');
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    BarcodeScanner.scan().then((result) => {
                if (!result.cancelled) {
                this.barcodeText = result.text;
                this.barcodeFormat = result.format;    
                this.scanningDone({
                    'text': result.text,
                    'format': result.format
                });
            }      
        }, 
            (error) => {
            console.log('error when scanning product barcode');    
        });    
    });    
}
}

**Scanned-page.ts**

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController,NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home'
@Component({
templateUrl: 'scanned-page.html',
})
export class ScannedPage  {
rootPage = HomePage;
private bcData;
constructor(private navCtrl: NavController,navParams: NavParams) {
this.bcData = navParams.get('data');
}
}

**app.module.ts**

import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { ScannedPage } from '../pages/scanned-page/scanned-page';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
declarations: [
MyApp,
HomePage,
ScannedPage
],
imports: [
IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
],
bootstrap: [IonicApp],
entryComponents: [
MyApp,
HomePage,
ScannedPage
],
providers: [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you add the page to `app.module.ts` as well?

Comment: @LuisEstevez oh yess., I did..I have added my app.module file now.pls have a look at it

Comment: DId you add it under `declarations` and `entryComponents` section of `app.module.ts`? Make sure that the path is correct.

Comment: have you confirmed that `'../pages/home/home'` is actually the correct path?

Comment: @Und3rTow  yes it is the correct path. I have confirmed it

Comment: @YuvaneshGowtham I just checked my ionic2 project, the page path in my page classes are `../home/home' not `../pages/home/home` do the same for scanned page class. Only for those two files, app.module.ts is correct.

Comment: in `ScannedPage` change import to `../home/home` or `../../pages/home/home`

Comment: @LuisEstevez thank you..,the runtime error has been solved..,but I am getting a complete blank white screen when i run ionic serve..,I am not getting my scan button

Comment: @suraj thank you.., the error is solved but i am just getting a blank screen